# TypeScript undefined object type messes things up

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am often running into a situation where I store an object in React state, such as a User:

```
...
user: undefined,
setUser: (user) => set((state) => ({ user: { ...user, ...state.user } as User })),
```

I define the TypeScript type as

```
export type User = {
  verified: boolean;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  userType: 'user' | 'admin';
};
```

So, at the moment TypeScript will complain that `user`, which I instantiate as a `User` type is `undefined`, while it cannot be. FINE! So I add `| undefined` at the end of the `User` type definition. So that will take care of this specific file, but then I start getting a million and one other warnings all over, because, for example, I call `user.firstName`, but now that the user can be undefined, I really should call user?.firstName.
Adding conditions, such as `if(user)` does not seem to satisfy TS. So I end up spending three hours fixing stuff for TS, only to find out that my code now breaks because of this recent change.
It feels very much like trying to put down fires that I started myself when I used TypeScript. Frustrating.

Can someone who know TS well please offer some guidance? How would you approach this? Is there a way to handle such "undefined" cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have defined user as:

```
const user: User|undefined = ...;
```

If you want to access a property of user, use this syntax:

```
user!.firstName
```

This tells typescript that you know what you're doing and that `user` is never undefined or null. It also tells typescript that properties accessed this way are not to be assumed to possibly be `null` or `undefined`, which I'm guessing is why you were now getting more errors.

---

#### Note!

```
const user: User|undefined = ...;
```

is redundant typing. You can just revert back to using

```
const user: User = ...;
```

but instead of using the `?.` operator to access properties, continue using `!.`.

Sorry if this is your first time using typescript. It's usually not this bad.

Comment: Helpful tip about the exclamation mark. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider splitting your components into:

- Components that MUST have a user
- Components that MAY have a user

From the component that may have a user, render the component that must have one.

```
class UserComponent extends React.Component<{ user: User }> {
  render() {
        // Note: since user must be defined for this component, we are able to access properties without the ? or ! syntax
        return (
            <div>{this.props.user.firstName}</div>
        )
    }
}

// Note: this.state.user is optional, and therefore is initialized as undefined
class MayHaveUserComponent extends React.Component<{}, { user?: User }> {
    render() {
        if (this.state.user) {
            return <UserComponent user={this.state.user} />
        }
        return (
            <div>No user yet!</div>
        )
    }

    setUser(user: User) {
      this.setState({ user: { ...user, ...this.state.user } })
    }
}
```

Comment: An interesting idea, but not going to work for my app flow.

Answer (score 1):

You're not just making typescript happy here. If you pass `user: undefined` to code that expects there to be a user object, then that will definitely cause runtime errors when you use `undefined` like an object. These checks are necessary if that is to be allowed.

Typically, I handle that in react by returning a render early if a required value is `null` or `undefined`. After that return, you can assume the user exists as normal.

```
class Component({ user: User | null | undefined }) {
  if (!user) return <SomeLoadingIndicator /> // or: return null, or whatever

  // from here on, `user` is known to be of type `User`, not null, and not undefined.

  return <div>{user.lastName}</div>
}
```

---

> Adding conditions, such as `if(user)` does not seem to satisfy TS.

It really does though. You just have to be on a conditional branch where the check has been run. Meaning you have to be in the `{ }` of an if statement:

```
const user: User | null = Math.random() > 0.5 ? getUser() : null
if (user) {
  // here user is of type: User
} else {
  // here user is of type: null
}
// here user is of type: User | null
```

Or in code that could *only* run if the conditional was truthy.

```
const user: User | null = Math.random() > 0.5 ? getUser() : null
if (!user) {
  // here user is of type: null
  throw new Error("user is required!")
}
// here user is of type: User
```

Comment: You are right about the condition being respected by TS. It was an error on my part. Good points here.